# Run Azure DevOps stage if no agent available

Tags: azure-devops, pipeline

End goal is to provision a build agent if one isn't already available.

Reason:

I'm currently provisioning build agents dynamically for each pipeline run, however, provisioning the Windows build agent on EC2 takes about 5 minutes to provision and configure (register in the ADO pool) and instead I'd like to leave a few build agents running from normal business hours, but still allow dynamic provisioning off-hours.

Is there a way to setup a `condition:` to check for pool/agent status? Or would setting up a stage to run some API calls to get the status of agents first and set some variable based on that, then check that variable status later be my best bet? Is anyone doing something similar?

Comment: Not an answer for your exact scenario, but you might still find it useful. Have a look at [How to create scalable agent pools in Azure DevOps](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1zeOFdPbrjk).

Comment: I would suggest to have some predefined agent pools with agents registered. You could scale these pools with KEDA or another tool off working hours

Comment: @rickvdbosch thanks, that looks like it could be helpful if we were using Azure, but we're using AWS as our cloud provider. That also appears to still require a minimum of 1 agent running at all times.